# Assign attributes to an image from the id of another element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have a list each item in the list contains an image and a map

```
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" />
  <map id="map-one"></map>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" />
  <map id="map-two"></map>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" />
  <map id="map-thre"></map>
</li>
```

to use the map on the img tag should I add the attribute usemap, for example in the first element of the list

```
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" usemap="#map-one" />
  <map id="map-one"></map>
</li>
```

to get the id of the maps I have done the following with JQuery

```
var $mapid;

$('.slides li map').each(function(i, elem) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $mapid = $this.attr('id');
});
```

using

```
console.log($mapid);
```

the result is the following

- map-one
- map-two
- map-thre

But now I don´t know as assigning to each image the usemap attribute and the value of this attribute is the id of the map to be used for coordinates.

like this

```
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" usemap="#map-one" />
  <map id="map-one"></map>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" usemap="#map-two" />
  <map id="map-two"></map>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" usemap="#map-thre" />
  <map id="map-thre"></map>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setter version of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), then you can return the id of the next element(which is the `map` element) prefixed with `#`

```
$('.slides li img').attr('usemap', function (i, elem) {
    return '#' + $(this).next().attr('id')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/40xazh4u/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need intermediate variable. You can just get previous `img` element and set its id directly:

```
$('.slides li map').each(function () {
    $(this).prev('img').attr('id', '#' + this.id);
});
```